# Is there a way to add add entries to the following dataframe in R

Tags: r

```
dt <- data.frame(name = "John",children = I(list(c(1,2,3))))
```

```
  name children
1 John  1, 2, 3
```

After trying this

```
dt[nrow(dt) + 1,] = c("Amos", I(list(c(3,4,5))))
```

I get the error

Warning message:

> In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nrow(dt) + 1, , value = list("Amos",  :
> replacement element 2 has 3 rows to replace 1 rows

Comment: Also use a `list()`. For example: `rbind(dt, list("Amos", I(list(c(3,4,5)))))`

Comment: FYI, iteratively adding rows to a frame *works*, but it scales poorly: if you are doing this repeatedly, then it will slow down to a crawl. The reason for this is that when you `rbind` two frames (or a frame and a list), it makes a full copy of the first frame. This means that if you have (say) 100K rows in a frame, and want to add 1 row to it, it must copy all 100K rows into a 100K+1 row frame; this slows as object size increases, and your 100K rows of data exist in memory twice (for some time until garbage-collection).

Comment: See "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: @r2evans this is exactly what I wanted to do, what would be the best option

Comment: It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the c()
A one-row data frame would be a list, not an atomic vector.
Try:

```
dt[nrow(dt) + 1,] = list("Amos", I(list(c(3,4,5))))
```

or:

```
dt <- rbind(dt, list("Amos", I(list(c(3,4,5)))))
```

Do note though, as per r2evans note below and the link to the R inferno, this is a way of doing things that gets very slow and memory-hungry with large data frames as they are duplicated for each new line.  There are better ways to approach the issue, my answer is just intended to address why your original code was not working.

Comment: Please be careful making this recommendation: it's bad practice, and highly discouraged in all but the simplest execution. See my comments about how it scales poorly, and an informative (and mildly entertaining) read is "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: Oh, I agree - I'm answering the question "why isn't it working?" rather than "how should I do this?"  Generating a list of rows and rbind() ing them at once would be better, or defining the data frame at full size then filling it.  I won't add any more detail here as your link to the inferno covers several good options.